# Conversion of gson.JsonObject to Json.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, automation, jackson, gson

I have a gson.JsonObject which is returned by a method. I want to convert that to org.json.JSONObject without any data loss.
I tried i tried gson library:

> JSONObject obj = gson.fromJson(JsonObject, JSONObject.class); or
>   JSONObject obj = gson.fromJson(JsonObject.toString(),
>   JSONObject.class); or
>
> JSONObject obj = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(JsonObject),
>   JSONObject.class);

something like this but i got a JSONObject with all the keys removed except some.
Am i missing something??

Comment: Try a simpler solution if not dealing with huge amount of data. Convert to a string, and use the string to create a JsonObject.

Comment: but i want JSONObject not JsonObject